# Converting Big endian to Little endian in C#

Tags: c#, endianness

Let me start by saying, I have looked at some of the post that are on Stackoverflow already. My problem is that I'm a beginner level programmer and have a hard time configuring there solutions into my project.

I'm currently struggling to convert one 'big endian' to a 'little endian'.

The currently have a float:

(4.61854E-41)

but I want to somehow convert it to look like this:

(-1.0)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: `problem is that I'm a beginner level programmer` - this is not a problem at all! Hint: Try to READ big endian not convert. Also first thing to do is get to know what is the actual difference between both off those endians: [Little Endian vs Big Endian](https://thebittheories.com/little-endian-vs-big-endian-b4046c63e1f2)

Comment: @Red-X even with those numbers you can't get from one to another. Are you sure is a endianess problem? Why do you think it's a problem with the endianess? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Magnetron I'm using a PLC program, that should give me real values. like (0.01mm), but i get numbers like (4.61845E-41) instead. So I emailed the company that makes the PLC system, and they said that I get a Big endian instead of little endian which I apparently need.

Comment: Ok, I got it, From your input it's not a double, it's a float

Comment: Even though, it's not a perfect match, `1.0` will convert to `4,600603E-41` and `4.61845E-41` to `0.25`

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [BitConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

First you check if your system is little endian or not and then reverse the bytes depending on that.

```
float num = 1.2f;

if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num);
    Array.Reverse(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    num = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
}

Console.WriteLine(num);
```

Comment: Even in that case, you can't get from 2.247E-41 to 1.2 or vice-versa. This answer might be close, but the question is incomplete.

Comment: @Red-X this answer should work for you, just change the input from double to float and `num = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);`. If you get the same result after conversion, try drop the `if`

Answer (score 6):

In 2022 the right way to go is using [`BinaryPrimitives`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives?view=net-6.0).

```
    float num = 1.2f;

    if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    {
        int bits = BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits(num);
        int revBits = BinaryPrimitives.ReverseEndianness(bits);
        num = BitConverter.Int32BitsToSingle(revBits);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(num);
```

This is much better optimized performance-wise and uses the [`bswap`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/bswap) instruction on modern x86 processors.
The ARM equivalent for this is [`REV32`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0802/a/A64-General-Instructions/REV32).

See [JIT-CodeGen](https://godbolt.org/z/YYcaqG7q9) diff between this and the [answer of @sLw](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51611667).

The BinaryPrimitives are available from .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Standard 2.1.
As a .NET Framework user, the legacy way is still the best way (Reference: [.NET API Catalog](https://apisof.net/catalog/9a0e190a-cb13-7f39-9088-fce2634c9a19)).